# diffence between to_owned().into_iter() and iter() to iterate string array in rust

Tags: rust

```rust
pub fn capitalize_first(input: &str) -> String {
    let mut c = input.chars();
    match c.next() {
        None => String::new(),
        Some(first) => first.to_uppercase().to_string() + c.as_str(),
    }
}

// Step 2.
// Apply the `capitalize_first` funciton to a slice of string slices.
// Return a vector of strings.
// ["hello", "world"] -> ["Hello", "World"]
pub fn capitalize_words_vector(words: &[&str]) -> Vec<String> {
    words.iter().map(|w| capitalize_first(w)).collect()
}

// Step 3.
// Apply the `capitalize_first` function again to a slice of string slices.
// Return a single string.
// ["hello", " ", "world"] -> "Hello World"
pub fn capitalize_words_string(words: &[&str]) -> String {
    words
        .to_owned()
        .into_iter()
        .map(capitalize_first)
        .collect::<String>()
}
```

Which method is better?

I wrote the first method based on my previous java knowledge. I saw the second one, `.to_owned().into_iter().map(...)`, on a rustling solution git repo

Can anyone explain to me what are the difference, and which one is better in this case?

Comment: Please [do not post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).

Comment: If `capitalize_first` takes a `&&str` or an `impl AsRef<str>`, then the `capitalize_words_string` function can also be written as simply `words.iter().map(capitalize_first).collect()`.

Comment: "Which method is better" - The return type of the two functions are different. Which return type do you need?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### First function:

```rust
pub fn capitalize_words_vector(words: &[&str]) -> Vec<String> {
    words.iter().map(|w| capitalize_first(w)).collect()
}
```

This one is pretty much how I would do it. You could avoid the `w` variable by converting the `&&str` elements into `&str` via `copied()`. Apart of that I think this solution is fine:

```rust
pub fn capitalize_words_vector(words: &[&str]) -> Vec<String> {
    words.iter().copied().map(capitalize_first).collect()
}
```

### Second function:

```rust
pub fn capitalize_words_string(words: &[&str]) -> String {
    words
        .to_owned()
        .into_iter()
        .map(capitalize_first)
        .collect::<String>()
}
```

This one isn't quite optimal, in my opinion.
`to_owned` creates a copy that simply isn't necessary, as you iterate over it anyway. So converting an iterable object into an owned object just so you can convert it back to an iterator via `into_iter` really doesn't serve any purpose.

I would use the exact same semantic as in the first one. You don't even need `::<String>`, that is automatically derived from the return type:

```rust
pub fn capitalize_words_string(words: &[&str]) -> String {
    words.iter().copied().map(capitalize_first).collect()
}
```

---

The official solution seems to state:

```rust
pub fn capitalize_words_string(words: &[&str]) -> String {
    capitalize_words_vector(words).join("")
}
```

While that most certainly works, I would disagree with it being optimal, because just like `to_owned().into_iter()`, it creates a redundant copy. (meaning it computes all of the words first, stores them, and then consumes them again. `iter().copied().map(capitalize_first)` doesn't require iterating twice, it is fully streamed.)

**Important:** Claims about performance like the ones I make here are purely heuristic. If this was a real world problem, do **NOT** perform heuristic performance analysis. Do some actual benchmarking instead. Compilers are magic, and many times improvements like the ones talked about here don't matter because the compiler already optimized it away already. **Don't waste time on optimization without benchmarking first**, and then **benchmark whether your optimizations are actually optimizations**.

In this specific case I would argue that the official solution is the 'cleanest', because it has the least amount of code duplication. Code duplication, and with that, maintainability, is a much more important metric in most real world projects than the last 2% of performance. I've seen too many projects die due to maintainability issues, and it pains me every time.

Comment: I have to disagree with your anwer’s **important** section. Even though compiler and LLVM _may sometimes_ optimize out allocations, you still __*really__* have to care about not allocating stuff yourself, and does compiler optimize or not doesn’t matter in this case.

Comment: @Miiao You really don't have to care about that too much, if it doesn't impact the important performance metrics of your program. Of course to a certain degree it's good practice, but further than that, I'd argue that readability is more important than performance, unless the performance is insufficient. And the only way to find out if it is sufficient is by benchmarking. I'm talking real world projects here where maintainability and actually getting them done is more important than gaining the last 5% performance.

Comment: @Miiao Of course as soon as there are performance critical sections every little bit is important, but even then I've seen people waste days on 'optimizations' that turned out to have zero effect. Benchmark where your bottleneck is, understand it, and then fix it. Instead of wasting days of work on a point where you *think* the bottleneck is without confirming in benchmarks first.

Comment: ok, I understood what you meant. (pretty useless comment, but I had to reply or something)

Comment: @Miiao I just mentioned it because SO answers always talk about how to optimize, but only very rarely mention *if* things should be optimized in the first place. Especially to new programmers, I have seen that they get lost in micro-optimizations because that's how they have seen it on stackoverflow or other websites like codewars. It is of course important to have clean best practices, but beyond that, it's important to understand at what point it is enough; and if one has to go further, where to prioritize optimizations.

Comment: To apply it to this specific case: I'd argue that the official solution is the cleanest, because whilst being potentially slower (even though the compiler might be able to optimize), it's the solution with the lowest amount of code duplication. And that, imo, is a much more important metric than the last 1% of performance.